# logstash filter split breaks workflow

Tags: parsing, logstash

split filter breaks our filter chain: in manual we found

> The split filter is for splitting multiline messages into separate
>   events.

http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/filters/split

but we don't know how write next chain

input -> filter split -> filter grok -> output

just try use split and grok in same filter section, but it not work

```
 filter {
    split {     }
    grok {
      pattern => "%{NGINX}"
      }
   }
```

input, output and separate use on split and grok works fine, but when we use split and grok together - after split grok doesn't called

Please advise how we can split big message and then parse it by grok

Comment: Please provide your log example.

Comment: Post your logstash conf file please.

Comment: nginx access or error log?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug.  See https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1312

Also see the first comment which indicates to use the `mutate` filter:

```
mutate {
    split => ["message", "\n"]
}
```